# angular2 observables filter each array element than return it to an array

Tags: arrays, angular, rxjs, observable

I have an array of Threads Objects with ID, title and a isBookmarked:boolean.

I've created a Subject and I want to subscribe to it in order to get an array of Thread Objects with isBookmarked=true.

https://plnkr.co/edit/IFGiM8KoSYW6G0kjGDdY?p=preview

Inside the Service I have

```
export class Service {

  threadlist:Thread[] = [
    new Thread(1,'Thread 1',false),
    new Thread(2,'Thread 2',true),
    new Thread(3,'Thread 3',false),
    new Thread(4,'Thread 4',true),
    new Thread(5,'Thread 5',true),
    new Thread(6,'Thread 6',false),
    new Thread(7,'Thread 7',false),
    ]

  threadlist$:Subject<Thread[]> = new Subject<Thread[]>()

 update() {
   this.threadlist$.next(this.threadlist)
 }

}
```

in the component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 localThreadlist:Thread[];
 localThreadlistFiltered:Thread[];
 constructor(private _service:Service){}

 ngOnInit():any{
  //This updates the view with the full list
  this._service.threadlist$.subscribe( threadlist => {
    this.localThreadlist = threadlist;
  })
  //here only if isBookmarked = true
  this._service.threadlist$
    .from(threadlist)//????
    .filter(thread => thread.isBookmarked == true)
    .toArray()
    .subscribe( threadlist => {
      this.localThreadlistFiltered = threadlist;
    })
  }
  update() {
    this._service.update();
  }
}
```

which Instance Method do I use in general to split an array?
Also is there a better way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: For the filtering, you could've done `this.localThreadlistFiltered = localThreadlist.filter(i=> i.isBookmarked)`. Also, why are you using a `Subject`? All you have is an array that you are passing around. Is there a stream of threads may be ?

Comment: yes the threadlist is supposed to be passed around in multiple components in a forum i'm building with angular2. This code is just for the sake of explanation. 
I want the filtering being done in the stream, and i know there has to be some operator to split the arrays

Comment: Yes, there is a [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) , and [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)  . `splice`, modifies the array. While `slice` returns a copy of the array modified. is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: i'm not sure, i've added the code above to a plunker. What i originally wanted is an operator that splits the array elements, do the filtering and the use the toArray operator

Comment: is this what you want ? https://plnkr.co/edit/sCRWXxpad5ciNj0SsKbo?p=preview

Comment: YES excatly... thanks! feeling kinda stupid now...I was fixated on an operator called mergeMap (which i just dug up...)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would leverage the `filter` method of JavaScript array within the `map` operator of observables:

```
this._service.threadlist$
  .map((threads) => {
    return threads.filter((thead) => thread.isBookmarked);
  })
  .subscribe( threadlist => {
    this.localThreadlistFiltered = threadlist;
  });
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/COaal3rLHnLJX4QmvkqC?p=preview.